# Feeding an XML document in Sitefinity 5

Tags: asp.net, xml, rss, content-management-system, sitefinity

I have an XML document in my "Feeds" folder of the root App_Data folder in Sitefinity v5. How can I get this to feed on my page? Do you know of any online tutorials?

I have tried using the Feeds settings, Javascript in a block, and other techniques. Or how do I convert my XML into an RSS so Sitefinity can better read?

If you can provide any help or insight, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you,

Maria

Answer (score 0):

is this a document you produced for internal use within the sitefinity application? I think the easiest way to go would be to create a simple user control (.ascx) that binds the xml to a repeater or similar control then register that user control as a widget as shown here: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/adding-controls-to-the-toolbox

then you can simply drop this widget onto any page.

If I've misunderstood your question please let me know more about what you're trying to accomplish and I'll try to help!